# Delete row of custom table in WordPress using AJAX

Tags: ajax, wpdb, customization

From my custom table (`$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'user_req';`) I'm showing data with `$wpdb->get_results()` and a foreach loop:

[image: my table]

I managed to update the database with the individual values from the form where there is a "Submit" button. But, from this table I want to delete any of the row by clicking on the `(x)` button on the right of each row. I can use `$_GET[]` and can easily delete the row, but in this case I want to use AJAX.

The `(x)` button on the right of each of the row is actually:

```
<input type="button" class="delete" title="Exclude This One"/>
```

I'm not a code-background, so I'm actually struggling with it. Most of the solution comes when I search, are for raw PHP-mySQL, but I'm trying to deal it with a WordPress way. I could prepare my $wpdb delete query:

```
<?php $wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'post_id' => $products->post_id ) ); ?>
```

But couldn't manage to go with it in an WordPress-AJAX way. Therefore, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Nonce

You are going to want to set a `nonce` hidden field  or to the element so that you can verify the request.  Take a look at the codex for examples.

#### Setting the POST ID and Nonce

You will need to add the id of the specific post to the delete button or to a hidden input field associated with that entry.  I have the example setup so you will need to add the `post_id` and the `nonce` to the element id in a format such as `#delete_postid_nonce`.  Your element ID would need to end up like so: `#delete_12_94f3a1e666`.

You could assign it using: `$element_id = 'delete_' . $products->post_id . '_' . wp_create_nonce('delete_' . $products->post_id );`

#### Add Actions

These need to be placed in functions.php or in a custom plugin.

You will notice there are two add_action calls.  One is for privileged users (i.e. they are logged in) and one is for non-privileged users.  Remove one or the other if you don't need both.  You can read more about that on the Codex.

#### Delete_Row() Function

This need to be placed in functions.php or in a custom plugin.

Here you are grabbing the `id` that we we sent in the `data` object of the ajax call.  That gets parsed and put in the the `POST` array since the `type` of the ajax call is set to `POST`.

Then you `explode()` the ID out of the element id sent in the ajax call (e.g. '#delete_12_94f3a1e666') which would leave you with `$id = array('delete', 12, '94f3a1e666');`.  So the post_id is equal to index `[1]`.

Then you `echo` to return `data` to the `success` portion of the ajax call.  And then you kill the php function by calling `die'.

---

You will need to modify this code to make it work 100%.

**JS:**

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var id = this.id;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "your_delete_action", "element_id": id},
        success: function (data) {
            //run stuff on success here.  You can use `data` var in the 
           //return so you could post a message.  
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
function delete_row() {
    $id = explode('_', sanitize_text($_POST['element_id']));
    if (wp_verify_nonce($id[2], $id[0] . '_' . $id[1])) {
                $table = 'yourtable';
        $wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'post_id' => $id[1] ) );

        echo 'Deleted post';
        die;
    } else {
        echo 'Nonce not verified';
        die;
    }

}

add_action('wp_ajax_your_delete_action', 'delete_row');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_delete_action', 'delete_row');
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for the details answer. But, I'm afraid, I can't understand the `if( wp_verify_nonce( $id[2], $id[0] . '_' . $id[1] ) )` portion. Can't match this portion with other tutorials (like [this one](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)). And with no changes to your code, if I run my page it's throwing a fatal error on the second product - showing: Can't redeclare function `delete_row()`. I pasted both the function and `<script>jQuery(document).on...` inside the loop.

Comment: They are doing it a different way on that tutorial.  Perfectly valid way.  When you explode the string `delete_12_94f3a1e666` you come up with `delete` at  array index [0], `12` for array index [1], `94f3a1e666` for array index [2].  If you look at the function reference, the first param of `wp_verify_nonce` is the nonce then the nonce_name.  I am checking the nonce in the if statement.  `delete_row()`: it seems that there is another function named `delete_row()` on your install.  Rename this one.  You don't want the function inside the loop.  In your functions.php file or a custom plugin.

Comment: When you change the function name you will need to rename it in the `add_actions` as well.  This code is not copy/pasteable.  I do not know your complete setup.  You need to modify it to your specific setup.  For example: in the `delete_row()` function you need to properly setup `$wpdb->delete()` because it will not work as is.

Comment: Can you be on [the loop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) for a chat with me?

Comment: @Mayeenul Islam: What questions do you have at this point?  I can point you to appropriate resources.  You are very close to making this work.  Make sure you have the `debug bar` plugin installed!  Also use the javascript console in your browser to debug the javascript!

Comment: *The function doesn't need to be in loop* - that's the key command for me. I transferred it to the `functions.php`. Renaming is not necessary, because it's conflicting because it's actually dual called when inside a loop. Ok. Now I opened the Console, it's showing an **Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not defined** when clicked on the button. I enqueued jQuery library at the beginning.

Comment: Good one.  You need to specify the path to ajax.php: try this just below `var id = this.id;`: `var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';`  Where is the javascript located?  On the page?  It will be easy to use php there.  Make sure it is outside of the loop otherwise it will be redeclared.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13233/discussion-between-mayeenul-islam-and-commandz)